# How do I make objects and text stand out over a busy photo background?

Tags: design-principles, critique, composition, contrast

I frequently have to place objects and text on photo backgrounds and some backgrounds make it hard to see the objects.

To get good contrast I will try to pick a background image that has large flat areas to place text and objects.

If that is not available I may try to put colored shapes behind the objects, dark for light text and vice versa.

Additionally I may try drop shadows or glow to set them off, but this is not always an option either.

In this case I have multi colored logos on a green and blue plant background that is busy.

I would like to avoid putting a shape between the objects and the background as it will cover the background.

They are currently shown with a white drop shadow. Two on bottom have a black drop shadow.

[image]

Any advice is appreciated.

Here are objects and foreground:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the overall goal of the image? In other words, why *must* there be a busy background? And is editing the background, such as a blur, or gradient overlay, not a possibility?

Comment: The goal is a marketing piece (a trade show banner). There does not have to be a busy image. A "Field of Flowers" was requested. I'd like to use this photo and I'd like to use any busy photo and be able to place things where I want despite whats in the background.

Comment: Can you supply the flower photo as one image and all the logos on a transparent background as a second image? Would be a lot easier to answer that way.

Comment: Beyond the immediate digital solution I would look at fine art for interest on the subject. I went to a fine art college then uni where we were still painting and drawing in year 4 of a graphics degree. From Piero della Francesca to Turner to Monet they all understood how to position items in a painting for priority and depth of field using various techniques. For example, with an abstract backdrop the eye will be drawn to anything sharp - your text / icons. Warm colours tend to come forward and cool colours recede. Proven techniques, remain valid.

Answer (score 8):

There are a ton of possibilities, all of which depend upon the actual content.

A dark gradient...

[image]

A light gradient....

[image]

Blur and adjust levels .....

[image]

Probably my favorite technique... a band of offsetting color with a mask to promote depth....

[image]

Or lower the opacity of the color bar... to make it even more dynamic overall...

[image]

I, personally, dislike using things like drop shadows and glows when possible. They have become too "canned" and pedestrian in many areas such as this.

Comment: My favorite technique at least in InDesign has always been an outer glow.  I'm surprised you don't mention that—or is it not possible in Illustrator?

Comment: By glow I meant outer glow. A nice hazy but bright outline can help offset the foreground. When you use a contrasting color for drop shadow it has a similar effect. Also just a solid stroke around objects can help them stand out.

Comment: As posted in the answer.. I'm not a fan of glows and shadows to push contrast. I'm not saying they won't work.. just not my go to method ever.